# WordPress Blog Not Displaying Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom template using the twentythirteen template. When I activate the template the blog posts disappear from the front page. I've used the same process to make the new template as I did for my own.

You can see my blog page here, http://www.gnarlydigital.com/blog/ and the new blog that I'm working on is here, http://www.flowdirectpumps.com/news/.

I've tripled checked all the code and both templates are identical. I've uploaded the Gnarly Digital template and it works.

Can anyone see anything obvious?

This is the index.php file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container pageContent">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you need to display custom post types on your homepage?

Comment: The /news page is the default blog post page. All blog post should display on this page. The whole site isn't WordPress, it's just a WordPress add on.

Comment: What do you mean "The whole site isn't WordPress, it's just a WordPress add on"

Comment: The News page is the only page that is WordPress. All the other pages, Home, Products etc are just standard HTML5.